# Как поменять заглавную букву имени новой ветки через intellij idea

Tags: intellij-idea

Создаю новую ветку через intellij idea
например

```
feature/...
```

IDE переименовывает ее в

```
Feature/...
```

Пробую в ручную изменить заглавную букву на строчную, все равно переименовывает в заглавную.
Версия IDE 2021.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была решена изменением имени директории с заглавной на строчную букву в папке самого Git. Теперь все ветки в моем проекте начинаются со строчной буквы. Не понятно в чем проблема, получается, что IDEA почему то не различает строчные и заглавные буквы, а так как первую ветку я создал с заглавной буквы, то папка в git была создана точно такая же и из IDE я ее уже не могу переименовать.